# The most efficient way to find the first 1 in an unsorted binary vector

Tags: optimization, search

Consider an unsorted binary vector V of 0's and 1's. The task is to find the first 1
in V. Although V is binary it is quite time-consuming to determine whether an element of
V is 0 or 1. Because of this I need to adopt an efficient searching strategy.

If V would be sorted then I could benefit from binary search and its low complexity of
O(log n). For my problem if I follow a linear search then it would be rather expensive. Therefore,
I am wondering whether I can solve my problem with a time complexity between O(log n) and O(n).

Any idea is greatly appreciated

Comment: If the array is not sorted, a linear search is optimal. There is no better method. If you can pre-compute the array to be sorted, then a binary sort would be better, but sorting the array is typically done in `O(n log n)` time. Since the array contains integers, you can certainly use a radix sort to do that. Since they are 0-1 integers, you can even use a partition. Both runs in `O(n)` time (optimal).

Comment: The complexity matters for large array but optimisations can drastically speed up the computation. For example, you can store the 0-1 values as a sequence of bits. Then you can search a one by inspecting 64-bit integers. In fact, you can use SIMD instructions to do that (eg. 128-512 bits). You can stop the computation when a 1 is found. This can be several order of magnitude faster than a naive search and very fast even for quite large arrays (<10e6 items).

Comment: Thanks Richard, it seems that you have assumed that "I know my binary set in advance". This is the core of difficulty. If I know the set I need to find the first 1 then I really do not care which algorithm to choose. If you ask me to tell you whether the 7th element is 0 or 1 then it takes around 30 seconds. Imagine, the length of my set is 10^6. So, you see that a linear search is not really wise.

Comment: But, you are right that using optimizations it is much faster. I tried to solve my problem this way but it seems that the underlying optimization problem is not so easy, For instance, in bellow you see a MATLAB code to solve my problem using genetic algorithm:

Comment: A=[zeros(1,10^4) 1 zeros(1,100) 1 1 zeros(1,10^3)];
cost=@(i) i+10^8*(1-A(i));   % here, 10^8 is used but in theory we need to choose 'infinity'
options = optimoptions('ga','Display','iter');
[x,f] = ga(cost,1,[],[],[],[],1,length(A),[],1,options)

But, unfortunately it often fails to find the true solution which is x=10^4+1. Instead, if
often finds x=1 as the true solution which is wrong.

Comment: Suppose the first 1 is at index K, and suppose an algorithm does *not* inspect all elements before K. There is no way for that algorithm to know whether K is the answer or not. So there is no hope for doing this in general. If your problem has any structure to it, maybe you can do better.

Comment: Hi Harold, yes. In that case the algorithm fails. But, it should be possible to solve this problem using optimization, for instance. But, before using optimization I want to see whether there is a better idea.

Comment: *"the 7th element is 0 or 1 then it takes around 30 seconds"*  Why checking *one* item is so slow in the first place? Note that even a binary search would be slow on 1e6 values with 30 s fetches (10 minutes)... This looks like a XY problem to me. By the way, MATLAB is known to be very slow for a lot of tasks except maybe matrix multiplication.

Comment: Optimization algorithms can only do better than a brute force search if your problem has exploitable structure, eg a genetic algorithm cannot find the single 1 in a large array of zeroes except by accident